What determines the validity of the Private Key in WIF format?
I understand the sha256 64 string hexadecimal "manually" can be altered, but in case of WIF Private Key the generate one must have very specific strings, and it is really difficult to alter these strings yourself, but not impossible, I mean that I have rarely gotten valid addresses trying to alter strings of a previously obtained WIF Private Ke


I have rarely gotten valid addresses trying to alter strings of a previously obtained WIF Private Key

The Wallet Interchange Format (WIF) has a four byte checksum within it. This means that almost all alterations will fail a checksum test, making the altered string not valid WIF.
The entire purpose of WIF is to detect and prevent the use of such alterations, i.e. to detect transcription errors.
